# TortoiseHg - cmdserver: timed out

Tags: tortoisehg

I'm getting the following error with pretty much any operation with TortoiseHg - commit, push, update. Lots of people seem to get code 255 but I haven't found much if anything on code 0 (or perhaps code -1). Anybody know a solution? Command line works fine, as does SourceTree (though the latter is hideously slow).

[image]

Windows 7 64 bit, TortoiseHg version 4.1.1, Mercurial 4.1.1, Python 2.7.10, PyQt-4.11.4, Qt-4.8.7. I would tag this tortoise-hg but apparently that doesn't exist and I don't have the rep to create it.

Comment: We are experiencing this too. Windows 7 64-bit as well. Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: It just started working again as mysteriously as it stopped.

Comment: Tagging with the exact error message that I got to help Google find this QA "cmdserver: timed out waiting for message"

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mercurial-ja/1bskOMqLDmw and translated.

> Try increasing the timeout for now. The default is 5 seconds.
>
> [tortoisehg] 
>   cmdserver.readtimeout = 300
>
> If this helps, I think the hg process is stalled for some reason. If
>   it doesn't, there may be dust in the interprocess communication.
>
> Note that readtimeout is the timeout for inter-process communication,
>   so it has nothing to do with the time required for pull processing.

Add the following to your .hgrc file for the repository affected

```
[tortoisehg] 
cmdserver.readtimeout = 300
```

It worked for me - no more dust ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is still visible in 2018, with [this thread](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issues/5059/cannot-perform-any-operations-within), which includes:

> Check environment variables. If there's `%HG%`, try without it.
>
> I guess our command string parsing would have some problem on Windows because it [uses `shlex.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shlex.html).
>
> Check [`tortoisehg/thg` issue 5021](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issues/5021/).